# Have Integerated the ckeditor in django model but when saving the data from ckeditor django admin panel it is not saving to database , showing blank

Tags: django, ckeditor

[image]

**I am using RichText Field**
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

```
class Section(BaseContent):
image = ImageWithThumbsField(upload_to='static/%Y/%m/%d', sizes=((90,120),(180,240),(360,480)),blank=True,  null=True )
# image = ImageWithThumbsField(upload_to='static/%Y/%m/%d',blank=True,  null=True )
description = RichTextField("Section description. Appears in section home page", blank=True, null=True)
url4SEO = models.SlugField("SEO friendly url, use only aplhabets and hyphen", max_length=60)
summary = models.CharField("Byline/ Summary", max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
css = models.CharField("Section specific CSS", max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
allowContent = models.BooleanField("Should this section allow any content(such as News and Event)?", default=True)
parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
home_disp = models.BooleanField(default = False)
sub_description=RichTextField("Section sub description. Appears in section portfolio page", blank=True, null=True)
sub_image=ImageWithThumbsField(upload_to='static/%Y/%m/%d', sizes=((90,120),(180,240),(360,480)),blank=True,  null=True )
# sub_image=ImageWithThumbsField(upload_to='static/%Y/%m/%d',blank=True,  null=True )
is_active = models.BooleanField()
```

Comment: Have you installed it in your settings.py file?

Comment: The above issue is fixed  updated the CKEditor  static files and admin static files  inside my static folder so the issue got resolved

Comment: yes have installed it

Answer (score 0):

I had the older ckeditors and django's admin static files inside my project static folder I took the the updated static files from the virtual env and keep it inside my static folder thus it worked !!!